# Not able to install Django on window 10

Tags: python, django, pip, frontend

- Python 3.8.3
- pip 20.0.2
- I installed python and pip and also running react but now i am not able to create project not able to install django. I got some unexpected error which i show you on an image form bellow here.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9vOd.png)

Comment: Are you using a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Type the commands below in your CMD prompt:

```
python 

pip help
```

If it did not responce, your install is not complete